# Floating point exception in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I am getting a floating point error where I think I
shouldn't get one.  May be I am missing something obvious.

```
import graph; size(6cm);
real f(real t) {return sqrt(8*cos(2*t));}
draw((-4,0) -- (4,0));
draw(polargraph(f,0,0.25*pi));
draw(polargraph(f,0.75*pi,pi));
```

The last line gives problems.  Since $\cos 2\theta>0$ for $\frac{3\pi}{4}<\theta<\frac{5\pi}{4}$ I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: when I try to calculate `cos(1.5*pi)` in Asymptote, the result is `-1.83697019872103e-16`

Comment: I changed the function to sqrt(abs(8*cos(2*t)).  This works.